# Communication serial port with matlab

Tags: serial, communication, matlab

I am trying to communicate with a serial port trought matlab. This is my code:

```
delete (instrfindall)
clear all
close all
clc; 

s=serial('COM4');
set(s,'BaudRate',4800);
set(s,'DataBits',8);
set(s, 'Parity','none');
set(s,'StopBits',1);
set(s, 'FlowControl','none');
set(s,'Terminator','CR');
set(s,'TimeOut',5000); 

fopen(s)
%Move the probe radial
fprintf(s,'%s','RADIAL=100');

out=fgets(s);

fclose (s)
delete (s)
clear (s)
```

But i cannot make the serial port to answer me. 
Can you help me? Is this code right?

Best regards,

Comment: The baud rate seems a bit low. Have you tried higher rates, ex: 38400?